# AJAX - Getting value of radio button and sending it to PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I've been having this issue for a while now and I guess I'm stuck. I've been reading on how to use AJAX to send data to a PHP file.

The thing is, I don't really get how to take the value of a radio button in a HTML page and then send that value through AJAX to a PHP file which will then process that value.

So for example:

**If I had 2 radio buttons**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no">
```

*And I would like to take the value of those radio buttons and send it to my PHP file using AJAX.*

*Next I would be able to process those values in PHP.
How would I make it so that AJAX sends the value of the selected radio button to PHP?*

Thanks, in advance!

EDIT:

Full code:

**HTML File**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatePremium() {
        var input1= $("#premium-yes").val();
        var input2= $("#premium-no").val();
        $.post( "upd_premium.php", { input1: input1, input2: input2 } );
    }
</script>

<div class="usersRow2">
    <form action="" method="POST"><label>Premium:</label> <p class="text-info-premium"><?php echo ucwords($premium_check) ?><i class="icon-star"></i></p> <div class="controls-premium"><a href='#' id="edit-premium" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a></div></form>
</div>

<script>
$('#edit-premium').click(function() {
 var text = $('.text-info-premium').text();
 var input = $('<input type="radio" name="premium" id="premium-yes" value="yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="premium" id="premium-no" value="no">No <div id="premium"></div>')

 $('.text-info-premium').text('').append(input);
 $('#edit-premium').remove();
 $('<a href="#" id="update-premium" onClick="updatePremium()" class="btn">Update</a>').insertAfter('#premium');

 $('<i class="fa fa-times" title="Cancel Edit"></i> <br /><br /><br />').insertAfter('#update-premium');
 $('.fa-times').click(function() {
    location.reload();
 });

});
</script>
```

**PHP File**

```
if($_POST['input1'] == 'yes') {
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: There are millions of examples for this out there. You _could_ for example have taken a look here on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358980/getting-radio-button-value-by-ajax

Comment: @arkascha I'm quite new to AJAX. I'm looking for some help with creating this code. Maybe some easy to understand examples?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), a post is easy:

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Now, you need to get the values of the inputs and pass them to the post:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" id="input1">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no" id="input2">

<script>
    var input1= $( "#input1" ).val();
    var input2= $( "#input2" ).val();
    $.post( "yourphpfile.php", { input1: input1, input2: input2 } );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how would that look from the PHP page?

Comment: They will be available in your php file in the $_POST[] array. In particular, at $_POST["input1"] and $_POST["input2"] respectively.

Comment: Hmm, I tried using the code from your answer but unfortunately it did not work. I used `if($_POST['input1'] == 'yes') { header("location: index.php"); }`     in the PHP file.

Comment: @JamesSpence Nothing happens.

Comment: What does the `<form>` code look like around the two inputs? Make sure it's set to POST. i.e. `<form method="post">`

Comment: @JamesSpence It is set to post. Unfortunately still nothing happens.

Comment: Please post all your PHP and HTML.

Comment: Take the print_r outside of the if statement. Just print it at the top of the file to see if your even getting post data.

Comment: @BrandonSmith All I'm seeing now is `Array ( )`

Comment: Then your js isn't posting anything. Start debugging there.

Comment: Check to ensure that jquery is loaded before that second script is running. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @JamesSpence How do I check if jQuery loads before that second script? And, there are no errors in the console.