# adding radio-buttons to PHP/AJAX contact form

Tags: php, html, ajax, contact-form

I can't add radio-buttons to my contact form (PHP+AJAX). The code is working fine with normal inputs but when I'm trying to add radio-buttons after clicking submit button it just reloading the page.
I've tried to use:

```
formdata.append( "input[name='group_name']:checked", _("input[name='group_name']:checked").value );
```

or

```
formdata.append( "input:radio[name=group_name] :selected", _("input:radio[name=group_name] :selected").value );
```

but it's not working.

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Website Contact Form</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
 _("mybtn").disabled = true;
 _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
 var formdata = new FormData();
 formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
 formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
 formdata.append( "m", _("m").value );
    var group_name = $(".group_name:checked").val();
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.open( "POST", "example_parser.php" );
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
   if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
    _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks '+_("n").value+', your message has been sent.</h2>';
   } else {
    _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    _("mybtn").disabled = false;
   }
  }
 }
 ajax.send( formdata );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
  <p><input id="n" placeholder="Name" required></p>
  <p><input id="e" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" required></p>
    <p>Select your option:</p>
  <input id="r1" type="radio" class="group_name" name="group_name" value="option1">
  <label for="r1">Option1</label>
  <input id="r2" type="radio" class="group_name" name="group_name" value="option2">
  <label for="r2">Option2</label>
  <br /> <br />
  <textarea id="m" placeholder="write your message here" rows="10" required></textarea>
  <p><input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form"> <span id="status"></span></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and PHP parser

```
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['m']) ){
$n = $_POST['n']; 
$e = $_POST['e'];
$r1 = $_POST['.group_name:checked'];
$m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
$to = "email_adress"; 
$from = $e;
$subject = 'Contact Form Message';
$message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' '.$r1.' <p>'.$m.'</p>';
$headers = "From: $from\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
}
}
```

Any ideas? 
I've spent a whole day to figure it out. Help! :D

Comment: Check your browser's Javascript console for errors.  Also, is there a specific reason why you're using `FormData`?  If you don't need to (uploading an image or something), then you could save yourself some headache by removing it.

Comment: What exactly are you intending to do by this `$r1 = $_POST['input[name='group_name']:checked'];`?  I can pretty much guarantee it's not doing what you think (it's probably throwing a syntax error)

Comment: $r1 is just for example of how to collect data from radio-button that was selected. 
I dont know how to connect data from selected radio-button and send it to php parser that is sending form to e-mail.

Comment: I dont need to use this method. But I couldn't find any better tutorial on how to script contact form with validation and radio-buttons/checkboxes.

Comment: You get the value in PHP just like you do for any other input.  And on the Javascript side, the first argument to `formdata.append` is supposed to be the name of the element, again, just like all the others.  Have you considered using something like jQuery.  It would simplify a lot of this for you, and I think you'd benefit from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting radio button value by ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358980/getting-radio-button-value-by-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for your interest Patrick but probably I've seen every topic that is related to this case. The tricky part with radio-boxes is that the only one – the selected one needs to be collected and I cant figure it out how to do that. With normal static inputs this script is working just fine.

Comment: Did you go through the answer in the linked question?  It shows exactly how to do what you want.

Comment: Yes. I did. It's not working.

Comment: So please update your question to include your new code that reflects the changes that you made.  Also include what errors may be showing in your browser's Javascript console.

Comment: Okay. I did everything that you asked for :)

Comment: That error indicates that you haven't included the jQuery library.  I think you need to take a few steps back and spend some time learning the basics.  You seem to be a bit over your head here and are just plowing ahead without actually understanding what you're doing.  There are lots of guides and tutorials out there regarding using JavaScript and jQuery to do ajax requests, and using PHP to handle those requests.  But you need to be willing to actually _learn_, not just blindly copy/paste a few random lines.

Comment: You're completely right but I want to make it work now. Learning some javascript is on my to-do list for 2020. Now I'm not getting any javascript error and I can send message but value from selected radio-button is not in the message.